# Intersect (Pathfinder) a picture and shape on Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, crop

How to **subtract** a **shape from a picture** without using *Clipping Mask*?

I don't want to use *Clipping Mask* because it lefts a bouding box instead permanent crop.

See: **Left image** with bounding box (*Preview mode*) and **Right image** in (*Outline mode*)
[image]

I should use Intersect from Pathfinder, but **it just works on two shapes** and I want to do it with a **picture and a shape**.

Clipping Mask: **Object -> Clipping Mask -> Make** is the only way?

**Edit 1**: I could export the *clipped* image and after import it, but I am searching for a more elegant way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Clipping Masks or Opacity Masks are the only way.

Illustrator is *not* a raster image editor. You can not easily crop or change the shape of an embedded or linked raster image within Illustrator.

Newer versions of Illustrator would *not* show the rectangle outside the clipping mask. And there are third party plug ins like [Rasterino](http://www.astutegraphics.com/software/rasterino/) that bring some raster cropping functionality into Illustrator.

There is a **trick** you can use within Illustrator. . .

Rather than making a clipping mask

- Draw the shape you want the mask to be
- Fill the shape with white and set the *opacity* of the shape to 0% using the **Transparency Panel**.
- Select the raster image and the shape and choose `Object > Flatten Transparency`.

This will essentially cut a hole in the raster image which matches the shape. Just delete the remaining portions of the raster image you don't want.

Comment: WOW! Thank you a lot for answering me! By the way, Rasterino could solve this? @Scott

Comment: Yes Rasterino allows you to crop and manipulate raster images to a degree within Illustrator.

Comment: OMG. Your **trick** really worked. Thank you <3

Comment: I was not able to accomplish this with the Flatten Transparency trick, but I'm sure it is something I am doing. The poster's original Clipping Mask solution still worked for me. I used a Ellipse tool to draw a circle, lay it centered on top of an image I had pasted in an resized, and then set it's transparency to 0 on top of the pasted image, selected both, and then Object -> Flattern Transparency with no effect. Illustrator CC